# por que al mandar una variable con php me manda este errer Notice: Undefined index: idm in C:\wamp64\www\modificar.php on line 3

Tags: php

este codigo es que esta en el archivo consulta.php

```
echo '<td><a href="modificar.php?idm='.$consulta['IDempleado'].'"  title="m"> 
                          <img alt="m" src="/imagenes/modificar3.png" width=\"1px\"></td>';
```

y este es el de modificar.php donde lo recibo

```
$idm = $_GET['idm'];
```

pero me dice que la variable $idm
Notice: Undefined index: idm in C:\wamp64\www\modificar.php on line 3

Comment: Hola, si tienes ese mensaje es que ese indice no existe en ese array en ese punto del programa. Haz un *debug* para ver que tiene dentro: `var_dump($_GET);`

Comment: si me manda algo C:\wamp64\www\modificar.php:3:
array (size=1)
  'idm' => string '16' (length=2)

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($_GET);` para verificar realmente qué datos estás recibiendo y con qué estructura.